# How create automation that get text value and set it to point in Autocad

Tags: vba, properties, automation, autocad

Need create macros/lisp/vba/diesel that user may do next steps:

- user clicking on TEXT on scheme and script getting this text value (it will be number) to buffer or into varialbe
- after that script changing cursor to PO (point)
- user will click on scheme and creates point
- our number from first steps will set automatically into point property as Z coordinate

How better to do it? With macros possible? Or need VBA or something else?

Comment: You should be able to do it with any of those languages. Personally, I find VBA to be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the simplest is AutoLISP

```
(defun c:foo (/ txt data z pt)
  (if (setq txt (car (entsel "\nSelect text: ")))
    (if (wcmatch (cdr (assoc 0 (setq data (entget txt)))) "*TEXT")
      (if (setq z (distof (cdr (assoc 1 data))))
        (if (setq pt (getpoint "\nPick a point: "))
          (command "_.point" (list (car pt) (cadr pt) z))
        )
        (prompt "\nSelected text is not a number.")
      )
      (prompt "\nSelected object is not a text or mtext.")
    )
  )
  (princ)
)
```